# Is Naive Bayes becoming more popular? Why?

Tags: naive-bayes, trend

This is the *google trends* result obtained for "Naive Bayes" phrase from Jan 2004-April 2017 ([link](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=naive%20bayes)). According to this figure, the search ratio for "Naive Bayes" in April 2017 is about %25 higher than the maximum in the whole time period. Does this imply that this simple and old method is gaining more attention? Why?
[image]

A reasonable explanation (according to the comment by Sycorax) is that this popularity is an indirect effect of the increasing attention to machine learning. But, it seems that some methods such as Naive Bayes are gaining more attention than others such as decision tree and SVM. This can be clear from the following figures:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Plausibly, more people are learning about statistics/data analysis/machine learning *generally,* which indirectly drives attention to Naive Bayes.

Comment: @Sycorax This seems reasonable. But, this trend cannot be seen for some other learning methods, such as SVM [link](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=svm).

Comment: Note that these graphs are only relative to the maximum. Generally SVM's star has wanted as Deep Learning has taken off in recent years -- machine learning tends to follow "fads."

Comment: "Decision tree" also has a 5 year high, and a very similar curve. Because of the hype on ML.

Comment: @Hossein if you have evidence that similar terms do not have the same kind of growth, that's relevant to your question and should be there rather than in comments.

Comment: @Glen_b, why isn't this closed as opinion-based? I do not see how anyone in cross-validated can answer this without relying heavily on opinions.

Comment: @Sycorax One can see this in google trends very nicely, btw: https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=svm,%22deep%20learning%22

Comment: @J.C.Leitão As asked, it's borderline (there may be some possibility of identifying a supportable reason) but because Matthew's answer (which denies the premise) is statistical, I decided that this was sufficient to leave it open for the present.

Comment: Why did you add random forest to this question? There is not much of a relationship between naive bayes and random forests. Obviously some techniques become more/less popular over time; i.e. deep learning exploded almost exponentially since 2004.

Comment: @amoeba You are right. Maybe it is the subject of another question, i.e., there is a different explanation for the popularity of different methods.

Comment: On top of machine learning driven interest as it has already been said, my guess is that some interest is due to the name of the method: when I started looking into machine learning, this was one of the first techniques that caught my attention due to the "naive" in it, I wondered "_what can that possibly mean_"?

Comment: My personal thought is that naive bayes is the simplest machine learning algorithm, the idea behind it being intuitively understandable by people without any sort of formal teaching.  So it ends up being a good one to use as an introduction.

Comment: Random thought: there seems to be some kind of seasonality in the "Naive Bayes" and "Decision Trees" graph. I wonder whether there is any reason for it. Maybe exam/master thesis/etc. periods?

Comment: @Glen_b I would like to accept an answer that combines some of the above comments. How can this be done? Is it natural that I myself answer the question based on these comments?

Comment: @Hossein If any of the commenters wanted to answer they should have done so by now; I don't think you should concern yourself over that. I entirely support any user who makes an effort to turn other people's comments into actual answers, as long as they credit their sources. With new comments I'd allow an hour or so but after that it should be free game. If you'd prefer you can nudge one of the commenters and ask if they wanted to make their comments an answer, but if you want a combined answer you might as well post one.

Answer (score 15):

I'd be cautious about over interpreting Google trends.

[Here's naive bayes (blue) vs. k-means (red)](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=%22naive%20bayes%22,k-means). What does it mean? I can make up a story that common variation is due to machine learning classes that teach both naive bayes and k-means. But that's just an educated guess, not an answer. I really don't know.

And unless we start surveying people who search for "naive bayes" I don't see how anyone can positively answer this either.

[image]

Comment: If you look closely at the dates of each peak, they coincide with the typical exam preparation time of universities, around November and April.  Note, "typical" is based off my experience in North America.

Comment: @calvin I can verify that I've made such searches recently but my course work has no bias towards just bayes.